# How to disable Challenge Friends Button in Games Center?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, game-center

[image]

How can i disable Challenge Friends Button? Please help me!!!

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, thats not possible.

The moment you add support for Achievements or Leader-boards to your app and that app is run on iOS 6+ "Challenges" will be available to the user.

Note, challenges are not to be confused with multiplayer, to support challenges under iOS 6 you don't need to change anything in your code ;)